# Accessing elements from queue which are part of an array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I have a probably very simple question but I can't see the solution.

First, I have a struct named Seed with the following code:

```
struct Seed
{
    int x, y;
    int i, j;
    int Type;
};
```

I then create a 2D array and a queue, respectively, like so:

```
Seed Grid[ROW][COL];
std::queue<Seed> SeedsToUpdate;
```

I populate the grid with a loop:

```
void CApp::LoopSeeds(int function, int Type)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < COL;j++)
        {
            switch (function)
            {
                case SET:
                    SetSeed(i, j, Type);
                    break;
                case DRAW:
                    DrawSeed(i,j);
                    break;
                case GROW:
                    GrowSeed(i,j,Type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I set individual seeds in the array to other types, such as `GREEN`. I then fill the queue by going through the array and filling it with all array elements that have the `GREEN` type:

```
void CApp::BuildQueue()
{
    for(int i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < COL;j++)
        {
            if (Grid[i][j].Type != SEED_EMPTY)
            {
                SeedsToUpdate.push(Grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, everything is good (I think). However, what I want to do is the following: for each seed in the queue, edit the neighbouring cells in the array, something like       `Grid[i+1][j].Type = GREEN;`

And here is my problem: how do I do that, given the above code?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: It seems like you have the indexes to the arrays in your `Seed` objects, so what is the problem? How to loop over the items in the vector?

Comment: You're right, I just realised that as I was going over the code. I no longer have a problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11

```
for(const Seed& seed: SeedsToUpdate){
    if (seed.i + 1 < ROW){
        Grid[seed.i+1][seed.j].type = seed.type
    }
}
```

C++03 with Boost

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const Seed& seed, SeedsToUpdate){
    if (seed.i + 1 < ROW){
        Grid[seed.i+1][seed.j].type = seed.type
    }
}
```

In C++03 (without Boost)

```
for(std::queue<Seed>::const_iter it = SeedsToUpdate.begin(); it != SeedsToUpdate.end(); ++it) {
    const Seed& seed = *it;
    if (seed.i + 1 < ROW){
        Grid[seed.i+1][seed.j].type = seed.type
    }
}
```

Also you should be using std::array/boost::array instead of raw arrays.

Comment: I think one of those will do the trick, I'll try them right now. Question though, why should I use std::array/boost::array? I'm wary of having overly-complicated code and never could find good enough reasons to do that.

Comment: Because it makes your code simpler, safer and more generic. The real question is why wouldn't you use them.

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look at it. Also, I fixed what I wanted to do, I realised that I was saving the i and j in the Seed objects by default and it was easy-peasy afterwards (looks much like your first solution, but without the pointers).

Comment: Actually, none of the examples I wrote use pointers directly.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty straight forward actually. Inside your inner loop, do something line

```
if (i+1 < ROW) {
   Grid[i+1][j].Type = GREEN;
   SeedsToUpdate.push(Grid[i+1][j]);

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not what I need this to do. What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the green seeds in the array, and update their neighbours without adding those neighbours to the queue (otherwise it will update the neighbours as well, and keep updating them until the grid is full).